# Pass parameter to jquery function when using class

Tags: jquery

I have my html tag as

```
<img src="D:\img1" class="date"/>
```

my jquery is

```
$(".date").click(function(e) { alert(e) });
```

I wanted to know how to pass the value "e" from img tag

Comment: What value from the `img` tag are you looking for?

Comment: why dont add the Html code here, instead of a screen shot. you can also add your code in http://codeshare.io or in http://jsfiddle.com

Comment: I cant understand why is this question upvoted :/

Comment: And where does `C#` come in? It is not clear what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: The `e` parameter is the *event object* which is passed by jQuery - it relates to the event being fired on the element (in this case the `click` event). You have access to this in your callback so I don't understand what it is you need to "pass"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(".date").on("click", function() {
    var $this = $(this); //clicked elemnt
    var attributeValue = $this.attr("atribute-name");
    // some more code
});
```